# Make code more efficient or quicker

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I've been using various bits of code to help me get to where I need.

The spreadsheet updates the quantity of a stock item in a main table (worksheet "Stock") with a value from "JDW" worksheet.

The VBA Code filters the main table to find the correct part number based on an input on the JDW worksheet.

The code then loops until it finds the first row that is NOT "hidden" by the filter. This is the bit that takes ages - an offset only moved it to row 2 not row "x" - this could be anything from row 2 to 5000.

The code then offsets to the correct cell, copies pastes, and then offsets again and copies the date and pastes the date value in to the next cell (adds date to a column titled "Last updated")

The code then clears the input form of the data as a basic "reset".

Any suggestions?

```
 Range("C4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Stock").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$5000").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("JDW").Range("C4").Value
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Do Until Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End If
    Loop
    Selection.Offset(0, 16).Select
    Sheets("JDW").Select
    Range("C20").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Stock").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
    Sheets("JDW").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Stock").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$5000").AutoFilter field:=1
    Sheets("JDW").Select
    Range("C20").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: Why are you using an autofilter? Is there only one matching entry on the sheet `Stock`?

Comment: Questions with working code are usually off-topic and might be better suited for CodeReview SE.

Comment: If this your code works as intended, only in a painfully slow way, indeed the folks over at CodeReview.SE will be happy to help you make it better, cleaner and more efficient :)

Comment: Voted to close with "This question belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)."

Answer (score 1):

Two things...

Firstly, there is a method on a range to do `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. You can loop through this and work only with the visible cells.

Secondly, get rid of `Select` and `Selection` - it is bad practice and slow. For example, refer to things like `Sheets("JDW").Range("C20")` and rather than use the copy/paste buffer you could do things like `Sheets("Stock").Cells(1,2).Value = Sheets("JDW").Range("C20").value` to put a value in directly...

Comment: Good idea  to use xlCellTypeVisible. You best use it with `Sheets("Stock").Range("$A$2:$X$5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1)` to find the desired row

Answer (score 1):

- Don't select other ranges all the time: You can get values, copy or paste without changing the selection.
- Loop through the rows instead of through the cells, do you don't have to apply the EntireRow function
- Avoid taking the wrong address first and then using .Offset to go to the right one
- If you just need to copy a value, do not copy the cell. Read the value from the source and write it to the destination.

This reduces the code to

```
Sheets("Stock").Range("$A$1:$X$5000").AutoFilter _
    field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("JDW").Range("C4").Value

Dim StockRow as range
Set StockRow = Sheets("Stock").Rows(2)
Do Until StockRow.Hidden = False
    Set StockRow = StockRow.Offset(RowOffset:=1)
Loop
StockRow.Cells(1,17).Value = Sheets("JDW").Range("C20").Value
StockRow.Cells(1,19).Value = Sheets("JDW").Range("A1").Value

Sheet("Stock").Range("$A$1:$X$5000").AutoFilter field:=1

Sheets("JDW").Range("C20").ClearContents
```

*(Not tested because I don't have the context)*

But actually you can do even better with

```
Dim StockRow as range, stockKey as variant
stockKey = Sheets("JDW").Range("C4").Value
Set StockRow = Sheets("Stock").Columns(1).Find(stockKey, LookAt:=xlWhole)
...
```